# Using PHP Pear mail :Failed to add recipient:

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I am using Php Pear mail for sending an attachment to the user who fills out a form. If I hard code the "to email" address it works fine. But when I use 
$to = $_POST['email'] ; I get the following error.

Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 501, response: <@localhost>: no local part)]

```
<?php

require_once 'Mail.php'; 
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';




$from = "email@domain.com";
$to = $_POST['email'] ; 
$subject = 'Free Diagnostic Test Coupon';

$headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

$text = 'Please find attached the coupon';// text and html versions of email.
$html = '<html><body>Please find attached the coupon</body>        </html>';

$file = 'img/coupon.jpg'; // attachment
$crlf = "\n";

$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'image/jpeg');

//do not ever try to call these lines 
$host = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
in reverse order
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the post parameter $_POST['email'] will hold email? 

Also I am pretty sure you need to add it as "email@domain.com <email@domain.com>"

Comment: I used the following <?php
   echo str_replace('  ', '&nbsp; ', nl2br(print_r($_POST, true)));
?> 
and  i got  Array
(
    [name] => Hafeez Ahmed
    [email] => email@domain.com
) Also as per your suggestion I updated to $to = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

Comment: Do you still get same error?

Comment: Also have you updated the from email parameters?

Comment: No error now.. just blank screen of php page.. yes updated from email parameter as well.

Comment: Add this in the top 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Thank you so much  for your guidance. Its working. If you notice there is a line "in reverse order" which should have been commented.. Appreciate your help...

Comment: Well vote the solution to be solving your problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code by adding the top of it.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```